# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor deadlock

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, concurrency, future

Our app is using the Spring @Async to start asynchronous tasks (e.g. to do parallel calls to REST APIs). Our ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has been configured with 16 corepoolsize, 128 maxpool and 128 queue size.

Asynchronous tasks can start more async tasks and so on, these can become quite deeply nested. With enough concurrent requests coming in combined with slow response times on called REST API, we can easily end up in deadlock. All the tasks in the corepool are waiting for the results from child tasks in the queue. Child tasks in the queue will not get executed as the corepool is full. Thus a deadlock.

Out async methods look like:

    `@Async
    public Future<String> asyncCallAPI() {
        return new AsyncResult<>(callAPI());
    }`

What would be the best approach to avoid these deadlocks?